# Javascript that communicates with a Hosted API?

Tags: javascript, c#, api, azure, azure-sql-database

Basically I'm developing .NET API that allows a certain Javascript to access a Database through it. The database contains User Information and the API is the mediator between the client (running the javascript on their websites) and the database. The javascript simply gets the data from the DB and displays them.

My problem is, where do I host my API so that the client Javascripts can access it? What is this system called? I'm using Microsoft Azure SQL Databases to store the user information. How do I access my C# API from the client's javascripts? Do I need to host my API on Azure's API Hosting service? Very confused.

> 1) Client adds the Javascript and a HTML div to their website
>
> 2) The Javascript should access the API
>
> 3) API accesses the Database and gets the Data (Which is completed and it works)
>
> 4) Send the Data to the client and the javascript populates it

I just need to figure out how to make a connection between the API and the javascript on the client's website

Do I need to use [THIS](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ASP.NET Web.Api. It allows you to build a REST endpoint in C# that you can host on the Azure platform as well. You will be able to host it using the web sites features of Azure. Even though you want to build an API not a web site hosting it in a web site container will give you what you need:

- Easy hosting solutions
- Web endpoints for your client JavaScript to consume
- C#.NET
- Web endpoints close to your database. (Host them in the same data center)
- Scalability
- Monitoring
- Ability to create a web site at the same address if you need to.

I haven't used Azure api management so I can't comment on that, but you will be able to get an ASP.NET Web.Api site up very quickly.

Comment: Oh man, perfect! Can you point me in the right direction with a documentation please, Aran? Do they have a documentation for setting up a WebAPI?

Comment: After setting this up, how do I connect the Javascript to it like I've mentioned in my question, mate?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api is the official site. It is one of the project options when you create a asp.net web project in visual studio as well. You can set up publishing to Azure as part of the project setup

Comment: The pluralsite videos in that link are good value too (they are on the right hand side)

Comment: Do you know how to make AJAX requests? That is how JavaScript communicates (from the browser) with a server.